# How to properly cancel parallel asynchronous IO Task by Escape key?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, cancellation-token

I am learning async await operations and have found a [very useful article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj155757.aspx).

I consider the the last code snippet from this article:

```
public async Task ProcessWriteMult(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
string folder = @"tempfolder\";
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
List<FileStream> sourceStreams = new List<FileStream>();

try
{
    for (int index = 1; index <= 10; index++)
    {
        string text = "In file " + index.ToString() + "\r\n";

        string fileName = "thefile" + index.ToString("00") + ".txt";
        string filePath = folder + fileName;

        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);

        Task theTask = sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
        sourceStreams.Add(sourceStream);

        tasks.Add(theTask);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

finally
{
    foreach (FileStream sourceStream in sourceStreams)
    {
        sourceStream.Close();
    }
}
}
```

I have tried some code to cancel tasks, however, imho, these are very ugly attempts. In this attempt my program flow waits for pressing key by user, but I would like this code to work till user press Esc button, like event:

```
if(Console.ReadKey().Key==System.ConsoleKey.Escape)
    cts.Cancel();
```

How can I properly cancel by Escape key?

UPDATE:

I've inserted this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
    ProcessWriteMult(cts);
    if(Console.ReadKey().Key == System.ConsoleKey.Escape)
        cts.Cancel();
}
```

However, this code does not cancel method `ProcessWriteMult(cts)`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you explored BackgroundWorker, it might be the best fit for your scenario here since it supports cancellation out of the box and executes work on a separate thread as well.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker(v=vs.110).aspx

Also see this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20627/BackgroundWorker-Threads-and-Supporting-Cancel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't use `async void`. I'm not sure why the MSDN example encourages bad practice, but still, don't do that. Using `async void` means you're method is "fire and forget", it can't be asynchronously waited, and any exception that happens inside it will be thrown on a thread-pool thread. Instead, use `async Task`.

Now, .NET 4.0 introduced the concept of `CancellationTokenSource`, which helps you do *cooperative cancellation*. This means that you have to monitor on the token in order to know someone from "the outside" requested cancellation. This can be done as follows:

```
try
{
    for (int index = 1; index <= 10; index++)
    {
        // Monitor the token, you decide where.
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        string text = "In file " + index.ToString() + "\r\n";

        string fileName = "thefile" + index.ToString("00") + ".txt";
        string filePath = folder + fileName;

        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);

        Task theTask = sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
        sourceStreams.Add(sourceStream);

        tasks.Add(theTask);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

> However, this code does not cancel method ProcessWriteMult(cts). What
>   am I doing wrong?

It could be that by the time you press escape, the method already finished executing. You can test this by awaiting `Task.Delay` on a certain interval (lets say, 5 seconds), and only then monitoring the cancellation token.

Comment: The `Console.CancelKeyPress` event might be a better alternative to polling if the OP is willing to trade Esc for Ctrl-C. Otherwise +1 :)

Comment: @Noseratio OPs today are spoiled. It's all about Esc ;p

Answer (score 1):

There is two types required for cancellation: one is the source another is a listener. I.e. you need an instance of `CancellationTokenSource` that would trigger the cancellation and your code should listen for the cancellation via the token:

```
Task ProcessWriteMultAsync(CancellationTokenSource source)
{
  // ...
}

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
await ProcessWriteMultAsync(cts.Token);
if(Console.ReadKey().Key==System.ConsoleKey.Escape)
           cts.Cancell();
```

And please, do not use `async void`! They should only be used for event handlers.